# Accessing resource key in custom attribute

Tags: c#, enums

I have written a custom attribute to support localization with enum descriptors.Here is my Code

```
 public class LocalizedDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    ResourceManager _resourceManager;
    string _resourceKey;

    public LocalizedDescriptionAttribute(string resourceKey, Type resourceType)
    {
        _resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourceType);
        _resourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            string description = _resourceManager.GetString(_resourceKey);
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description) ? string.Format("[[{0}]]", _resourceKey) : description;
        }
    }
}
```

and I support localization like this

```
 public enum Shape
{

    [LocalizedDescription("STR_SQUARE", typeof(MyResources))]
    SQUARE

}
```

but here if a resource string is deleted from resource file ,there will be no compile time error. I want to write attribute in such a way that if the resource string is deleted from resource file ,my code should give compilation error.

I do not know why I am not able to do this and how can I achieve below mentioned with custom attribute.

```
 public enum Shape
{

    [LocalizedDescription(MyResources.STR_SQUARE, typeof(MyResources))]
    SQUARE

}
```

Comment: The very fact that your resources are in the resource file will not allow you to get compile-time errors. The resource file is only read at runtime. You might need to move your list of resources into the code or handle the verification as part of your unit/integration testing.